# Cordova - Android HTTPS requests fail on 4G

Tags: android, cordova, ssl

I've created Cordova Android app, and I'm facing this issue:

When on 3G/4G, whenever I try to make request towards my server I get the error:

```
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED.
```

When I am on WIFI everything works fine. This is not happening on all Android devices, I am facing this issue on Samsung Galaxy A5 (nd some other Androids).

I've discovered that if we use HTTP instead of HTTPS everything is fine.

Also according to https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
and
https://www.digicert.com/help/
everything seems to be fine with our SSL cert.

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Check your  Proxy settings. If possible remove the proxy and try again.

Comment: have you implemented payment gateway in your app ??

Comment: What does any payment gateway have to do with this? We are not using any external payment gateways, just Android in-app purchases

Comment: it blocks the proxy requests

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea

Comment: have you tried using http only?

Comment: Yes, as I stated in the 1st post, when using HTTP, everything is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because your provider is configuring a proxy in your device.
Try checking your current APN setting and deleting the fields proxy and port from it.

This also can be caused if you are using a port different from 443

Comment: Thanks for answer but my app is B2C app, with more than 100k+ active users, so the solution must be within  the app, I cannot rely on the users to configure their proxies

Comment: There is no solution you can implement within the app, this only affect to users with a proxy set, not all of them will have it set, this depends on the provider.

Comment: But for example whats app, facebook and similar apps are working without any problem on this device, shouldn't they have same problem as well ?

Comment: are you using a port different from 443 for your https website?

Comment: I am using 8443, i could try using 443, but I cannot test this before tomorrow, as soon as I test it, I'll report back, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yeah, that could also cause the problem, I've edited the answer

Comment: I have run some test, and as far as I can say the problem was 8443 port, thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have found your answer or not, but still want to post answer for others looking for the solution: Note that **Cordova doesn't allow https calls to Servers with untrusted ssl certificate installed on them**. You can ignore this error and continue by making a small change in a cordova file.

> **Open** “\cordova\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\
>   CordovaWebViewClient.java”. In '**onReceivedSslError**' method, **comment
>   the else part and add handler.proceed() instead.**

Answer (score 0):

This issues happens with mobile data connection because the default Access Point that came with carrier generally have proxy that will not allowing SSL Tunneling. All you have to do is to set Proxy and Port to nothing.

Also ensure to use only port 443 for HTTPS.